# Upload S3 directories to an FTP

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need a class that takes a folder on S3 and uploads all its content, including other folders and files to a FTP directory. 
What's the best optimized way to handle that?

```
var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client();
var request = new ListObjectsRequest()
              .WithBucketName("My.SimpleBucket").WithMarker("MyFolder");

 using (ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request))
 {
    // here I can get Key and Size and BucketName of each object, 
    // but to get the stream of each object I gotta
    // do again request for each...
    // and this doesn't sound very right to me
```

Comment: [What Have You tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is actual just to use a protocol adaptor - try the S3 to FTP Storage protocol from SMEStorage. I use it for my CPanel Backup. It's at: http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=CloudFTP